# json KeyError - how to parse json output

Tags: python, json

Good morning I have a question regarding parsing json data, problem is I can't parse it via key. BTW I just started with python... This is my code:

```
nrq_data = {
    'query': '{\n  actor {\n    entitySearch(queryBuilder: {type: DASHBOARD}) {\n      query\n      results {\n        entities {\n          name\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n', 'variables': ''}

nrq_response = requests.post(
    'https://api.eu.newrelic.com/graphql', headers=nrq_headers, json=nrq_data)

a = json.loads(nrq_response.text)

print(a)
```

and here is an output:

```
{'data': {'actor': {'entitySearch': {'query': "type IN ('DASHBOARD')", 'results': {'entities': [{'name': 'C'}, {'name': 'C / C Overview'}, {'name': 'C / Errors'}, {'name': 'C / Transactions'}, {'name': 'C / VM Metrics'}, {'name': 'Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis'}, {'name': 'Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis / BOFU - Desktop'}, {'name': 'Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis / BOFU - Mobile and other'}, {'name': 'FirstOne'}, {'name': 'FirstOne / FirstOne'}, {'name': 'FirstOne-clone'}, {'name': 'FirstOne-clone / FirstOne'}]}}}}}
```

I need to read all "name" problem is when I'm trying do something like this:

```
 print(a['name'])
```

I'm getting KeyError. Is any possibility add keys or any other method to read only 'name' value?

Comment: Are you looking for `a.data.actor.entitySearch.results.entities[0].name` ?

Comment: all '''name''' values

Comment: @subodhkalika That syntax doesn't work for dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You have to navigate the dictionary. You need to find a dictionary somewhere in the hierarchy that has a key 'name'.

The key 'name' occurs in multiple locations in your sample data. Therefore a recursive approach is probably the way to go:

```
a = {'data': {'actor': {'entitySearch': {'query': "type IN ('DASHBOARD')", 'results': {'entities': [{'name': 'C'}, {'name': 'C / C Overview'}, {'name': 'C / Errors'}, {'name': 'C / Transactions'}, {'name': 'C / VM Metrics'}, {'name': 'Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis'}, {
    'name': 'Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis / BOFU - Desktop'}, {'name': 'Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis / BOFU - Mobile and other'}, {'name': 'FirstOne'}, {'name': 'FirstOne / FirstOne'}, {'name': 'FirstOne-clone'}, {'name': 'FirstOne-clone / FirstOne'}]}}}}}


def parse(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if 'name' in d:
            print(d['name'])
        else:
            for v in d.values():
                parse(v)
    else:
        if isinstance(d, list):
            for e in d:
                parse(e)


parse(a)
```

**Output:**

```
C
C / C Overview
C / Errors
C / Transactions
C / VM Metrics
Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis
Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis / BOFU - Desktop
Customer experience bottom of the funnel analysis / BOFU - Mobile and other
FirstOne
FirstOne / FirstOne
FirstOne-clone
FirstOne-clone / FirstOne
```